# How can I avoid getting Index error in the question sorting the output from a quadratic equation if the input is already sorted?

Tags: python

So I was trying this question on g4g:
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/sort-the-given-array-after-applying-the-given-equation0304/1#

Here I am using the idea to get the minima/maxima of the quadratic
equation so that I can apply the merge process(which is using two
sorted arrays to make a single sorted array containing both the
elements) Here A0 and A<=0 is used to get the nature of the parabola,
opening upward or downward

I am facing error at out.append(A*arr[i]*arr[i]+B*arr[i]+C) as
indexerror, list out of range. I am sure if x = 0 or x = len(nums),
then I'll get into trouble, but I am not able to think anything
otherwise:

Some of the test cases are:

1. A = 1, B = 1, C = 1. N = 3 Arr[] = {1, 2, 3}
2. A = -1, B = 2, C = -1. N = 6 Arr[] = {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

Here is my code for the same:

```
     class Solution:
            def sortArray(self, arr, n, A, B, C):
                # Code here
                #nums = arr[:]
                #print(nums)
                out = []
                nums = []
                for i in range(len(arr)):
                    nums.append(A*arr[i]*arr[i]+B*arr[i]+C)
                    
                x = -((B)//2*A) 
        
                #print(x)
                i = x
                j = x-1
                #out = []
                if i == 0:
                    return arr
                
                if A>0:
                    while j>=0 and i<len(nums):
                        if A*arr[i]*arr[i]+B*arr[i]+C<=A*arr[j]*arr[j]+B*arr[j]+C:
                            out.append(A*arr[i]*arr[i]+B*arr[i]+C)
                            i+=1
                        else:
                            out.append(A*arr[j]*arr[j]+B*arr[j]+C)
                            j-=1
                    
                    
                    while i<len(nums):
                        
                        #print(i)
                        out.append(A*arr[i]*arr[i]+B*arr[i]+C)
                        i+=1
                    while j>=0:
                        out.append(A*arr[j]*arr[j]+B*arr[j]+C)
                        j-=1
                    return out
                    
                elif A<=0:
                    
                     
                        
                    i = 0
                    j = len(nums)-1
                    while j>=x and i<x:
                        
                        if A*arr[i]*arr[i]+B*arr[i]+C<=A*arr[j]*arr[j]+B*arr[j]+C:
                            
                            out.append(A*arr[i]*arr[i]+B*arr[i]+C)
                            i+=1
                        else:
                            out.append(A*arr[j]*arr[j]+B*arr[j]+C)
                            j-=1
                    
                    while j>=x:
                        out.append(A*arr[j]*arr[j]+B*arr[j]+C)
                        j-=1
                    while i<x:
                        out.append(A*arr[i]*arr[i]+B*arr[i]+C)
                        i+=1
                    return out
                 
                   
                  
                
            

#{ 
#  Driver Code Starts
#Initial Template for Python 3

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        T=int(input())
        for i in range(T):
            a, b, c = input().split()
            a = int(a)
            b = int(b)
            c = int(c)
            n = int(input())
            arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
            ob = Solution()
            ans = ob.sortArray(arr, n, a, b, c)
            for each in ans:
                print(each,end=" ")
            print()

#} Driver Code Ends
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not simply derive the function array from the given inputs using `map` function and then sort the new array by any O(N) sorting algorithm. That would be much more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to break such a problem down into small junks that makes it way easier for you to understand what is happening and find errors. Also, you don't need to define a class for this problem, when you can just use simple functions.

I don't want to give a finished code sample, because I guess you like to solve the problem yourself, so here is a boilerplate that may help you to solve it. The body of the two functions should not be longer than maybe 10 lines of code, so if you end up with more lines, you should reconsider. Good luck :)

```
def calculate_new_array(arr, a, b, c):
    # calculate the resulting array out of the input values
    # ...
    # return resulting array
    return result


def sort_array(arr):
    # sort the array somehow
    # ...
    # return the sorted array
    return sorted_arr


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a, b, c = input().split()
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    c = int(c)
    arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

    new_array = calculate_new_array(arr, a, b, c)
    sorted_array = sort_array(new_array)
    print(sorted_array)
```

Small little spoiler: With python `N` is not that important.